# Symfony - how to make Doctrine search in abstract mapped superclass?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I am building an online shop for plastic model makers (hence the 'model').

I have a `Product` mapped superclass because I want all products (models, tools, paints etc. to have name, price and description):

```
<?php    
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo; // gedmo annotations

/** @MappedSuperclass */
abstract class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    //getters and setters...

}
```

Then, there's a `Model` class, for plastic models, this extends the `Product` class but also has a `Category` for being able to search from cars, aircraft, ships etc:

```
<?php    
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="model")
 */
class Model extends Product
{

    /**
     * @var Category
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="models")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }


}
```

There will of course be more classes extending `Product` mapped superclass. Now I want to select the 10 most recently added products, regardless of their kind (models, tools, paints).

How can I tell Doctrine to give me the last 10 added products? Of course I tried something like:
`$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("AppBundle:Product");`

but of course it throws an exception saying that

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'modeller_app.product' doesn't exist

which obviously is true, because `Product` is an abstract class and not actually an entity. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: From the [doctrine docs on mapped superclasses](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses): `A mapped superclass cannot be an entity, it is not query-able and persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must be unidirectional (with an owning side only).`

Comment: You clearly misunderstood the role of a mapped superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [class table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

Here is a example:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"product" = "Product", "model" = "Model"})
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    ...
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Model extends Product
{
    // Custom properties

    ...
}
```

Now you can query the Product entity and it will return the result from all entities that inherits it.